# Fixed header to 1140 grid system

Tags: html, css, layout, web, fixed

I am building website with [1140 grid system](http://cssgrid.net/).
I need help with fixed header. 
I have header with "`onecol`" for logo and "`elevencol last`" for menu aligned to right.

When I add lines

```
header{position:fixed;top:0;}
```

header doesn't take full width of page

Then I add

```
header{width:100%;}
```

And menu on right side goes too far to right.

If I add `max-width:1140px;` to header page looks good until you shrink it below 1140px and menu on doesn't fit in view.

I would appreciate if someone would like to help me. :)

Comment: If possible, add an image of what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

after `top: 0;` also add `left: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: besides that, I was also missing one container, now it works. Thank you sweet Ana. :)